# Showing decimal points in the annotations

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame such as:

```
      pt    car     walk    bike
EO    19221 15442   12932   1489
EW    19025 15484   12979   1494
Inc   21568 13650   12590   1276
Inc2  21705 13499   12608   1272
```

I want to have a percentage of whole values and show it in a bar chart.
I have written the following code:

```
Colors_list = ['#5cb85c','#5bc0de','#d9534f']

# Change this line to plot percentages instead of absolute values
ax = (df.div(df.sum(1), axis=0)).plot(kind='bar',
            stacked = True, figsize=(10,6),width = 0.4,edgecolor=None)
plt.legend(labels=df.columns,fontsize= 14)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xticks(rotation=0, horizontalalignment="center")


plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(True)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)


# Add this loop to add the annotations
for p in ax.patches:
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.annotate('{:.0%}'.format(height), (x + 0.05, y +  0.01), fontsize=14)
```

it works fine. the only issue is that it shows the percentage without any decimal point.
for example, it shows as:

```
26%    26%      26%    26%
```

however, I need to have:

```
26.35% 26.50%  25.65%  25.69%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.2` in `format` for 2 decimals:

```
ax.annotate('{:.2%}'.format(height), (x + 0.05, y +  0.01), fontsize=14)
```